# K-means with centres outside the data?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, svm

Say we want to split a cube in $\mathbb{R}^{64}$ into 10 pieces.
NN, nearest-neighbor or Voronoi splits,
take 10 cluster centres $c_0, \ldots, c_9$ in the cube,
e.g. from [K-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kmeans),
then classify a new data point $x$ by finding its nearest centre:
$$\text{NN}( x, c_0, \ldots, c_9 ) \equiv \text{argmin}_j\ \| x - c_j \| \text.$$

Kmeans centres are averages of data points, so fall near the data.
Could allowing centres outside the data give better splits ?
Is there a variant of Kmeans which converges e.g. to SVM weights,
viewed as points in the data space ?

As Suresh Venkat points out, "better" splitting,
better classification, is hard to define.

Comment: I'm not sure the definitions are right here.  In general I don't believe that the centres for the k-means problem will be data points.  Perhaps you're confusing it with k-medoids?

Comment: possibly the OP means "inside the hull defined by the data" rather than "at data points". Also, @Denis what does "better" mean in this context ?

Comment: I feel like the question is still overly vague, and is conflating a vague discussion of splitting with possibly a more specific discussion on SVMs. I'd encourage you to think more about this in order to get better answers.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Suresh, I'll try. (The goal is to improve Kmeans / bridge it to unsupervised SVM / understand the differences, but yes that's pretty vague.)

Comment: @Denis: Yes, and I think that makes sense (I've thought about that myself), but for this forum some specificity would help.

Answer (score 2):

Since k-means minimizes the within-cluster sum of squares, the cluster centers will *always* be the mean of the points within that cluster. If you use a different criterion, you are basically using a different method than k-means.

Comment: Rephrasing the question, is there a way of modifying the simple iterations of Kmeans to converge to e.g. SVM weights ? You're right, this would of course not be standard Kmeans.